# Horizontally center fixed width item under variable width item

Tags: css

I have a menu and certain elements have dropdowns.  These elements have variable widths.  I want the dropdown to be horizontally centered beneath its particular element.  The dropdown itself always has a fixed width.

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown {
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}
.container:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8AauA/

I've tried using `margin-left`/`left` with percentages or offsetting the fixed width of the element, but I can tell that this is not centered -- especially for *all* containers.  Is it possible to do this via CSS?

Comment: you might want to close those divs in fiddle ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dropdowns always have fixed widths, you could position them by [`left: 50%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) which is relative to their containing block's width and then align them center by a negative [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) as the half of their width.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/8AauA/2/)**

```css
.dropdown {
    /* other styles here... */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* = width / 2 */
}
```

---

However if they have dynamic widths, you could use CSS3 [`translateX()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#funcdef-translatex) function instead of negative margins to achieve the desired result

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/8AauA/4/)**

```css
.dropdown {
    /* other styles here... */
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

It's worth noting that transforms [are supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for this issue is

```
.dropdown { 
   /* other styles here... */ 
   left: 0; 
   right: 0; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

You may center position:fixed element with this approach as well!